# Is the Apple 60W MagSafe Power Adapter better than 2012 in that way that the yellow color situation does not happen anymore?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, power, magsafe

#### Introduction

For an old MacBook Pro bought in 2012 as:

- MBP 13.3/2.9/2X4GB/750/SD
- Model No: A1278

The cable of the `MagSafe` since years ago changed the color to "yellow" and many parts of the cable itself become *cracked*, it about a 98%. The partial "solution" is put a *masking tape* (the one made with a special paper - not plastic - with color white/cream) for each cracked part. It works since 5/6/7 yrs ago and so far ...

It seems it happens normally according with:

- [MagSafe Power Cable Going Yellow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53011/magsafe-power-cable-going-yellow)
- [Why doesn't a stripped/cracked MagSafe power cable shock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213200/why-doesnt-a-stripped-cracked-magsafe-power-cable-shock)
- [Will the "cracked" wire of a MacBook charger eletrocute me](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303768/will-the-cracked-wire-of-a-macbook-charger-eletrocute-me)

I have other laptops and well it only happens for the MacBook Pro. Of course this cable/wire is thinner than others products (HP, ASUS, etc).

**NOTE**

Here the voltage in my country is 220v

#### Situation

Because nothing is eternal, I want have as backup other MagSafe. I did do a research at:

- [Identify your Mac power adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)

That matches with:

> 60W MagSafe Power Adapter with "L" style connector
>
> 13-inch MacBook Pro models introduced in 2010 through 2012

- [Power & Cables - Mac Accessories](https://www.apple.com/shop/mac/accessories/power-cables?fh=4595%2B45d4&f=charger&page=1)

That matches with: [Apple 60W MagSafe Power Adapter (for MacBook and 13-inch MacBook Pro)](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC461LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-power-adapter-for-macbook-and-13-inch-macbook-pro)

And Yes, my current `MagSafe` has printed `60W MagSafe Power Adapter` too

#### Question

- Is the [Apple 60W MagSafe Power Adapter (for MacBook and 13-inch MacBook Pro)](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC461LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-power-adapter-for-macbook-and-13-inch-macbook-pro) better than 2012 in that way that the yellow color situation does not happen anymore?

I mean, **better material applied to manufacturing**. I am assuming this situation about the yellow case was reported since 2012 to Apple and it was fixed.

Furthermore, it has a cost of US$75.00, not cheap, and would be very bad experience if this "yellow" situation remains until now. So has no sense be buying this MagSafe each N years.

Comment: The yellowing is due to light & heat exposure. No bright light, no yellowing. I have a 2012 MBP with a charger & cables that look brand new. It's never been in sunlight or bright daylight, ever.

Comment: Many types of plastic materials exposed to heat will discolor and crack over time. The alternative is that they melt instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin The MagSafe has never exposed to the sunlight or bright daylight. It is located in my room. It only was - and so far - exposed to the common natural light is in my room.

Comment: Any smokers in the house?

Comment: No at all .....